# Index based assignment with apply in R

Tags: r, loops, apply

I'm cleaning up some survey data in R; assigning variables 1,0 based on the responses to a question. Say I had a question with 3 options; a,b,c; and I had a data frame with the responses and logical variables:

```
df <- data.frame(a = rep(0,3), b = rep(0,3), c = rep(0,3), response = I(list(c(1),c(1,2),c(2,3))))
```

So I want to change the 0's to 1's if the response matches the column index (ie 1=a, 2=b, 3=c).

This is fairly easy to do with a loop:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df2)) df2[i,df2[i,"response"][[1]]] <- 1
```

Is there any way to do this with an apply/lapply/sapply/etc? Something like:

```
df <- sapply(df,function(x) x[x["response"][[1]]] <- 1)
```

Or should I stick with a loop?

Comment: what is your expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *matrix indexing*, from `?[`:

> A third form of indexing is via a numeric matrix with the one column
>   for each dimension: each row of the index matrix then selects a single
>   element of the array, and the result is a vector. Negative indices are
>   not allowed in the index matrix. NA and zero values are allowed: rows
>   of an index matrix containing a zero are ignored, whereas rows
>   containing an NA produce an NA in the result.

```
# construct a matrix representing the index where the value should be one
idx <- with(df, cbind(rep(seq_along(response), lengths(response)), unlist(response)))

idx
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    1
#[2,]    2    1
#[3,]    2    2
#[4,]    3    2
#[5,]    3    3

# do the assignment
df[idx] <- 1

df
#  a b c response
#1 1 0 0        1
#2 1 1 0     1, 2
#3 0 1 1     2, 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this helps

```
df[1:3] <- t(sapply(df$response, function(x) as.integer(names(df)[1:3] %in% names(df)[x])))
df
#   a b c response
#1 1 0 0        1
#2 1 1 0     1, 2
#3 0 1 1     2, 3
```

---

Or a compact option is

```
library(qdapTools)
df[1:3] <- mtabulate(df$response)
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can try this .

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df1=df %>%mutate(Id=row_number()) %>%unnest(response)
df[,1:3]=table(df1$Id,df1$response)


  a b c response
1 1 0 0        1
2 1 1 0     1, 2
3 0 1 1     2, 3
```